# Redirect a URL to a an old site and a developing site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

New to this server arena.  I have an old website that is upa nd running.  I want to work on the new Wordpress site, however since it has to be online I need to be able to access it while the old site is still running.  I think I can do this from the .htaccess file, but, really sure how to set it up.  I would like to be able to go to the URL and after the .com enter the folder for the new site.  Is this possible??
Thanks
Markl

Comment: I guess I am not explaining things well.  The site is currently running when a user enters the url (Example www.oldsite.com ) I would like to put the new WordPress site in a directory inside the current directory that is running the old site (which is: oldsite.com)  So we can work on the new site I would like to be able to enter: www.oldsite.com/newsite/wp-login.php to get to the mainenance page, or www.oldsite.com/newsite.com to see the new site online.  Is that even possible???

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the site URL from wp_options table.

```
UPDATE TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "new domain" WHERE option_name = "siteurl"
UPDATE TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "new domain" WHERE option_name = "home"
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You can change site location temporarily in wp-config.php

`define('WP_SITEURL', "http://example.com/path");`

`define('WP_HOME', "http://example.com/path");`

You will also need [standard WP .htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) in new directory.